# how to implement ref cursor type in C# odbc connection?

Tags: c#, cursor, odbc, ref-cursor

i am trying to pass a ref cursor type in C# odbc connection. and i don't want use OracleClient because it is deprecated and will not be supported by future versions of .net.

Thank you for your help.